# Intuitive misconceptions

Tags: ancient-history, political-history, social-history, prehistory, cultural-history

Are there any ideas that one would have in History intuitively that would be disproven by analysis?

On the other hand, are there any intuitive historical ideas that have been verified by historians?

This could apply to any period in History. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to the History Stack. You might want to check out the [Tour](https://history.stackexchange.com/tour) and the section on [questions](https://history.stackexchange.com/help). This seems to be asking for a list of examples, and so would be difficult to address with a single, concise answer.

Comment: I was not necessarily asking for many examples. In fact, I just want to know if the cases are possible but thanks for redirecting me to the links.

Comment: Yes.  I am not sure the counterintuitives are shared.  Look for articles on myths about history, or "facts" you learned. Klarman's latest book is about the anitipopulist nature of the us Constitution.  Or the recent question on the emancipation proclamation.

Comment: Is the concept of an intuitive historical idea even meaningful in this context?  Seems as though "analysis" is often just the process of trying to replace one set of historical myths with another that better suits the analyst's political opinions - or his/her chance of attaining tenure through publication :-)

Comment: Do you mean intuitive like the way assume medieval Europe was racially homogeneous?  Or that everyone that time was religious?

Comment: @rougon Wait, do you mean that mediaeval Europe was not homogenous? Wow, now I'm an example of someone who held intuitive but incorrect ideas about History.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace Hi, what was the recent question on the Emancipation Proclamation?

Comment: @M.Harrow don't know why you take that personally, but a lot of people have that misconception. And I think we all carry some incorrect ideas about history, including historians!

Comment: @rougon Did I come across as offended? I most certainly was not, only pleasantly surprised.

Comment: @M.Harrow I assumed you were sarcastic, but if not, sorry to be prickly about it.

Comment: @rougon That's fine :)

Answer (score 6):

One example of such an idea is that the 20th century was especially violent. This is based on recollections of two world wars, enormous progress in arms technology, and comparison with the two previous centuries. However an analysis made by modern historians suggests that the loss of life due to violence (as a percentage of population) steadily declines if we look at long periods of history.

References: Lawrence Keeley, [War Before Civilization The Myth of the Peaceful Savage](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=Q8MHKQrFeEEC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false). Oxford UP, 1996. Steven Pinker, The better angels of our nature,
Viking, 2011. (There is no consensus on this, see 
Steven Pinker,
The Blank Slate, Modern Denial of Human Nature for exposition of various points of view).

Here is a little specific example from Pinker (he is talking here about criminal violence):

> When I surveyed perceptions of violence in an Internet questionnaire,
>   people guessed that 20th-century England was about 14 percent more violent
>   than 14th-century England. In fact it was 95 percent less violent.

Another common misconception is that people started to influence 
significantly their natural environment only with the beginning of the industrial era.
This is disproved by many examples both from history and pre-history. Examples: extinction of large mammals in Australia and Americas in pre-historical period.

Comment: A summary of [**War Before Civilization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Before_Civilization) by Wikipedia

Comment: One example of such an idea is the belief that you can measure violence by counting deaths.  However, an analysis of medical techniques suggests that many injuries that would have been uniformly fatal in 1900 were highly survivable in 2000.

Comment: @Mark: progress in medicine in the last 100 years has marginal impact on the trend that I tried to describe in my answer. I was talking on really long-time trend.